# horizontal textView autoscrolling doesn't work (singleLines deprecated)

Tags: android

> The aim is to make any text scroll automatically and horizontally inside a textview. I have tried to find the way, but the best my result looks like: xml

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text_album_artist_title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Single-line text view that scrolls automatically if the text is too long to fit in the widget"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        />
```

> code

```
textViewSongTitleAlbumArtist = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_album_artist_title);
    textViewSongTitleAlbumArtist.setSelected(true);
```

> It works, the text scrolls and everything is ok, but when I try to change the textview, it stops working. The xml is the same and the code is different:

```
textViewSongTitleAlbumArtist = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_album_artist_title);
    textViewSongTitleAlbumArtist.setSelected(true);
    textViewSongTitleAlbumArtist.setText(musicSrv.getCurrentPlayingSong().mTitle + " " +
            musicSrv.getCurrentPlayingSong().mArtist + " " + musicSrv.getCurrentPlayingSong().mAlbum);
```

> So I want to make any text that I set into a textview to scroll horizontally, automatically and unlimited number of times.

Comment: Try using ` android:scrollbars="horizontal" ` attribute inside <TextView> tag.

Comment: tried and no success

Answer (score 0):

Use the code

`textViewSongTitleAlbumArtist.setSelected(true);`

below this code

`textViewSongTitleAlbumArtist.setText(musicSrv.getCurrentPlayingSong().mTitle + " " + musicSrv.getCurrentPlayingSong().mArtist + " " + musicSrv.getCurrentPlayingSong().mAlbum);`

Comment: Maybe because the text exactly fits the space available. The scrolling only happens if there are no space for the texts to show up.

Comment: no doesn't work, I have added very long string, doesn't work

Comment: android:singleLine="true" try adding this to the textview xml once, remove the android:maxLines="1" line

Comment: it is deprecated, but i will try

Comment: Yes it is, but maxLines, does not work as singleLine does. Let me know if it works

Comment: thanks, but is there another way to achieve it without deprecated singleLines?

Comment: It worked? I don't know any other ways other than that. Try using these 
android:lines="1"
android:maxLines="1"

Comment: android:lines="1" android:maxLines="1" doesn't help to solve the problem, textview doesn't scroll text. it works only with singleLine"true" which is deprecated.

Comment: Then you gotta use singleLine"true" unless you find any other solution or unless android introduces any other code that does that. Let me know if you find any other solution to this. Also don't forget to give an up vote if my answer helped.